# Can't update without upgrading with new Tortoise 1.7

Tags: tortoisesvn, backwards-compatibility

I have downloaded `TortoiseSVN-1.7.0.22068-x64-svn-1.7.0.msi` and now it is impossible to update a project folder or commit any project files.

With this new version, Tortoise developers now are forcing us to upgrade the folder in order to use it. But it would loose backward compatibility: old tortoise clients cannot interact with the upgraded folder.

Is this correct?

We all have to upgrade our Tortoise clients in company or maybe wait for a backward compatibility feature on next Tortoise version?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Subversion 1.7 clients use a new working copy format. Subversion 1.7 clients cannot use Subversion 1.6 (and earlier) working copies. Existing working copies created with Subversion 1.6 and earlier need to be upgraded before they can be used with a Subversion 1.7 client

Yes, WCs must be upgraded to 1.7. Yes, 1.6 and 1.7 clients are uncompatible in the WC-handling, due to implementing WC-NG.

> We all have to upgrade our Tortoise clients in company or maybe wait for a backward compatibility feature on next Tortoise version?

No. Everybody **can leave** 1.6 TSVN and continue to use 1.6 working copies. Server-version at the same time can be any version

Answer (score 1):

Not everyone has to upgrade at once.  I am actually running tortoise svn version 1.7 on my laptop and an older version on my desktop.  It still works with the remote repository.  However the other svn clients that it is talking about are those on the same machine.  In other words, I also had to upgrade my SlikSvn to 1.7 and also Visual SVN too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, older clients will probably not work with working copies upgraded to SVN 1.7.  Note that TortoiseSVN is just forcing you to acknowledge the upgrade of your working copy; previous versions of TortoiseSVN would just upgrade your working copy to the latest SVN format without checking with you.

See the [release notes](http://tortoisesvn.net/tsvn_1.7_releasenotes.html) for more details, under the section "Upgrading the Working Copy".